# Rerender list in vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I use `moment.js` to display how many time has passed from some event.

I have a list (rendered using `vue.js`)

```
event 3, 5 seconds ago
event 2, 1 minute ago
event 1, 5 minutes ago
```

The problem is: list is not updated frequently (new items are added, for example, every 2 minutes).

I want to update `n (seconds|minutes) ago` strings.

Should I do simple loop using setInterval?

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
    let item = this.list[i];
    item.created_at_diff = moment(item.created_at).fromNow();
    this.$set(this.list, i, item);
}
```

or there is a better approach?

Comment: Shouldn't the strings be a computed property using the list? If that's the case, when you change the list the string should change too.

Comment: @Potray, how to write computed property for list `item`, but not the whole list?

Comment: Here is how you write computed properties: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do such a thing, tell me if I am wrong:

First, I would create a component that will make the timer:

```
let Timer = Vue.extend({
  template: '#timer',
  props: ['timestamp'],
  data () {
    return {
        formatted: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    format () {
      let self = this
      this.formatted = moment().to(moment(this.timestamp,'X'))

      // Uncomment this line to see that reactivity works
      // this.formatted = moment().format('X')

      setTimeout(() => {
        self.format()
      },500)
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.format()
  }
})
```

The timer takes one property, a UNIX timestamp in seconds. The component contains one method called `format()` that will update the only data `formatted` of the component. The method is recursive and calls itself every 500ms (with the `setTimeout()`), you can make this number bigger if you want.

Here is a jsFiddle I made if you want to test it:

https://jsfiddle.net/54qhk08h/